# Wordpress and Windows Live Writer

Tags: windows-live-writer

I've just been trying windows live writer with my WordPress blog. When I upload my posts from WLW to WordPress and then check them in the WordPress editor, they are a hideous mess of tags etc that describe the formatting (e.g. `<P>` and no line spacing etc), but aren't visible when I create and edit in the WordPress editor.

Is there a way to avoid this as it makes the WordPress editor very hard to use if I need to make edits outside of WLW. Or do people using WLW just give up on using the WordPress editor. I have to say I find the mess very offputting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this post](http://blog.joeware.net/2011/10/21/2335/), the poster had a problem of HTML tags being stripped of their opening and closing brackets when posting in WP from WLW'.

He explains the source of the problem, and his solution:

> The issue with the partially stripped HTML tags is a bug in libxml2. Specifically using anything less than PHP 5.2.9+ with libxml2 2.7.3+ is susceptible.  The fix is to install a plugin into WordPress called LibXML2 Fix which you can get from your plugins menu or look here -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/libxml2-fix/.

He goes on in explaining how you can find out what version of PHP and LibXML2 you are running, so you know if you're suffering from the same problem as he is.

Comment: Please try to include relevant information, rather than lone link to resource. Links are not eternal and are considered poor form of an answer.